# Eevee Eyeball procedural texturing

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders, glass

I’m trying to create this eye in Eevee Mode with procedural texture, but I get this strange effect on the iris.

Below I attach the shading nodes panel and the link of the tutorial I was following

https://youtu.be/1Nkx2CuaREc

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you turned on *Eevee render settings > **[X] Screen Space Reflection***, and *Eevee render settings > Screen Space Reflection > **[X] Refraction*** and in the material settings > *Settings >  **[X] Screen Space Reflection***? (render engine must be EEVEE to see this material setting)

Comment: if you're using transparency, in Eevee you need to enable Properties panel > Material > Settings > Blend Mode > Alpha

Comment: Yes I find this common error and a I turned on those setting @Blunder

Comment: No I'm using glass @moonboots

Comment: maybe pack the images and share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots 
https://pasteall.org/blend/87a389af3069466cbda6095b00eab6db

Comment: hello, could you please pack the images and share again?

Comment: https://we.tl/t-SELPGRY0YW @moonboots

Comment: it looks like you need to switch the Settings > Shadow mode to None? The glass must be projecting a shadow on the pupil texture

Comment: @moonboots thank you I find the error!! thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The glass must be projecting a shadow on the pupil texture, you need to switch the *Properties panel > Material > Settings > Shadow Mode* to *None*.